# MIPS ASSEMBLY How to use if's and else's translation from C to MIPS Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, mips, translate

So i have this code in C that i have to translate into assembly

```
    int a[10]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int i, j, k;
    i = 1;
    goto abc;
def:
        j = 1;
        k = 4;
    goto ghi;
    i = 2;
abc:
    goto def;
ghi:
    if (i==j){
        a[2] = a[3];
    }else{
        a[2] = a[4];
    }
    while(k>0){
        a[k] = 7;
        k = k - 1;
    }
    if((i>k) && (i<10)){
        if((k==6) || (j>=i)){
            a[9] = 400;
        }else{
            a[9] = 500;
        }
    }
    switch(j){
        case 0: a[6] = 4; break;
        case 1: a[6] = 5; break;
        case 2: a[6] = 6; break;
        case 3: a[6] = 7; break;
    }
```

I have been able to turn only the goto parts into assembly because i don't know how to turn the if's else's and switch commands into MIPS assembly
Here what i have done so far

```
.text
main:
    li  $t0, 1
    lw  $t0, variableI      ## i = 1
    j abc               ## goto abc
def:
    li  $t0, 1
    lw  $t0, variableJ      ## j=1
    li  $t0, 4
    lw  $t0, variableK      ## k=4
    j ghi               ## goto ghi
    li  $t0, 2
    lw  $t0, variableI      ## i = 2
abc:
    j def               ## goto def
ghi:
    
    

.data
variableI:  .word
variableJ:  .word
variableK:  .word
vetorA:     .word 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

It isn't necessary to translate all code for me just need a good explanation of how to use if's and else's since i haven't found any really good explanation online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instruction set manual is online that will cover all of it.  As well as compilers.

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b, unsigned int c )
{
    unsigned int r;
    
    r = 0;
    if(a==5)
    {
        r=6;
    }
    return(r);
}

mips-elf-gcc -O2 -c -fno-delayed-branch so.c -o so.o
mips-elf-objdump -d so.o

so.o:     file format elf32-bigmips


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   24020005    li  $2,5
   4:   10820004    beq $4,$2,18 <fun+0x18>
   8:   00000000    nop
   c:   00001025    move    $2,$0
  10:   03e00008    jr  $31
  14:   00000000    nop
  18:   24020006    li  $2,6
  1c:   03e00008    jr  $31
  20:   00000000    nop
```

equals and not equals are easy, bne, beq...

it is often common for the compiler to generate the opposite something like this in this case

```
return reg = 0;
compare input reg with 5
if NOT equal then branch to skip
return reg = 6
skip:
return
```

But not always, gcc did this

```
   0:   24020005    li  $2,5
   4:   10820004    beq $4,$2,18 <fun+0x18>
   8:   00000000    nop
```

r2 is the return register load it with a 5 as a temporary register for now in order to do the comparision.  compare the input reg (r4) with 5 if equal then branch to address 18.  If not equal keep going.

If not equal then

```
   c:   00001025    move    $2,$0
  10:   03e00008    jr  $31
  14:   00000000    nop
```

put a 0 in the return register r2 and return.  this path is the equivalent of

```
r = 0;
return(r);
```

If it is equal to 5 then

```
  18:   24020006    li  $2,6
  1c:   03e00008    jr  $31
  20:   00000000    nop
```

put the 6 in r2 and return

For this example C code the compiler is very brute force about the solution, other than not incurring more branches to have a single exit point (not-atypical).

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    unsigned int r;
    
    r = a;
    switch(b)
    {
        case 5: r+=3; break;
        case 7: r^=3; break;
    }
    return(r);
}
```

sometimes you will see the tools generate a jump table, depends on the architecture and other factors, in this case that is not going to happen but if you had switch(b&3) and then the four possible cases, I tried and gcc did not make a jump table.

But what is a switch really?  in this case and in all cases it is no more than if (argument in the parens, in this case just b by itself) b is 5 else of b is 7 then.  A switch is an if-then-else tree and often that is all a compiler will bother to implement.

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   24030005    li  $3,5
   4:   00801025    move    $2,$4
   8:   10a30009    beq $5,$3,30 <fun+0x30>
   c:   00000000    nop
  10:   24030007    li  $3,7
  14:   14a30004    bne $5,$3,28 <fun+0x28>
  18:   00000000    nop
  1c:   38820003    xori    $2,$4,0x3
  20:   03e00008    jr  $31
  24:   00000000    nop
  28:   03e00008    jr  $31
  2c:   00000000    nop
  30:   24820003    addiu   $2,$4,3
  34:   03e00008    jr  $31
  38:   00000000    nop
```

r = a

```
   4:   00801025    move    $2,$4
```

if b == 5 then

```
   0:   24030005    li  $3,5

   8:   10a30009    beq $5,$3,30 <fun+0x30>
   c:   00000000    nop
```

r+=3 and return

```
  30:   24820003    addiu   $2,$4,3
  34:   03e00008    jr  $31
  38:   00000000    nop
```

(else) if b==7

```
  10:   24030007    li  $3,7
  14:   14a30004    bne $5,$3,28 <fun+0x28>
  18:   00000000    nop
```

r ^=3 and return

```
  1c:   38820003    xori    $2,$4,0x3
  20:   03e00008    jr  $31
  24:   00000000    nop
```

else return (r was set to a up front)

```
  28:   03e00008    jr  $31
  2c:   00000000    nop
```

so it is a simple if-then-else tree with one non brute force out of order kind of thing the r = a was placed in the middle of the if b == 5 were mixed together.

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a )
{
    unsigned int r;
    
    r = 0;
    if(a<5)
    {
        r = 3;
    }
    return(r);
}


00000000 <fun>:
   0:   2c840005    sltiu   $4,$4,5
   4:   14800004    bnez    $4,18 <fun+0x18>
   8:   00000000    nop
   c:   00001025    move    $2,$0
  10:   03e00008    jr  $31
  14:   00000000    nop
  18:   24020003    li  $2,3
  1c:   03e00008    jr  $31
  20:   00000000    nop
```

because of how mips works or at least the mips I have compiled for

set if less than unsigned

```
   0:   2c840005    sltiu   $4,$4,5
```

since the way the C was written we can actually discard the a variable with the if less than question.  So if r4 (a) is less than 5 then "set" r4 (non-zero)

so now less than becomes an equal or not equal question

if(r4 is not equal to zero) combined with the above means if a is less than five then

```
   4:   14800004    bnez    $4,18 <fun+0x18>
   8:   00000000    nop
```

return 3

```
  18:   24020003    li  $2,3
  1c:   03e00008    jr  $31
  20:   00000000    nop
```

else return 0

```
   c:   00001025    move    $2,$0
  10:   03e00008    jr  $31
  14:   00000000    nop
```

Mips doesn't like/use flags like most other instruction sets.  Most others you would have a compare instruction which does a subtract and sets a bunch of flags but does not store the subtraction to a register, then subsequent instructions will use those flags. mips uses a philosophy of no flags so do the comparison and act on it in the same instruction.  So for example another architecture:

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e3500004    cmp r0, #4
   4:   93a00003    movls   r0, #3
   8:   83a00000    movhi   r0, #0
   c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

compare a with 4 then if less than or same r = 3 if higher r = 0 and return.  This is in a way also very atypical in that this instruction set shown here (arm) allows for per-instruction conditional execution rather than only branches are conditional and mov and add and such are not.

And this is more typical

```
00000000 <_fun>:
   0:   0a00            clr r0
   2:   2d97 0002 0004  cmp 2(sp), $4
   8:   8301            blos    c <_fun+0xc>
   a:   0087            rts pc
   c:   15c0 0003       mov $3, r0
  10:   0087            rts pc
```

and this is almost brute force one to one

r = 0

```
   0:   0a00            clr r0
```

compare a (passed in on the stack) with 4

```
   2:   2d97 0002 0004  cmp 2(sp), $4
```

branch if lower or same to address c:

```
   8:   8301            blos    c <_fun+0xc>
```

if 5 or higher then return (with r = 0)

```
   a:   0087            rts pc
```

if less than 5 (less than or equal to 4) then return 3

```
   c:   15c0 0003       mov $3, r0
  10:   0087            rts pc
```

(destination is on the right here mov $3,r0 means r0 = 3.  $ means constant here)

Comment: Well, thank you good sir this is just amazing! Helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Never thought I would use this knowledge again! Hope this helps.

It can help to look at a reference sheet and understand what the instructions are doing. Generally `if` and `else` can be simulated with "branch if equal" (**beq**) or "branch if not equal" (**bne**). Take a look at the below reference for those instructions.

Also, the `while` and `switch` use the same instruction - just think about how the code should flow.

Check out this reference for some more details on how to use the instructions, and others that I haven't mentioned. I will mention that most of the instructions should use registers, loading/saving words, branching, basic jumping, math, etc.

[https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/resources/MIPS_help.html](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs61c/resources/MIPS_help.html)

Comment: So the first 
if (i==j){
        a[2] = a[3];
    }else{
        a[2] = a[4];
    }


would become something like 
        la $t0, vetorA
 lw $t1, variavelI
 lw $t2, variavelJ 
 beq $t1,$t2, L2  
    ## case beq== false he does this
 lw $t1, 8($t0)
 sw $t1, 16($t0)  ## a[2] = a[4]
 j L2_fim
 L2:    ##case beq==true comes to here
  lw $t1, 8($t0)
  sw $t1, 12($t0)  ## a[2] = a[3]
 L2_fim:

can you tell me if this is correct?